# 2 part Access web form to be filled out by 2 people

Tags: database, sharepoint, ms-access, webforms

I have made something just like this using php and mysql. Just curious to know if this can be done in MS Access and then used on SharePoint.

Form has section A and B. Person to start the form will fill out section A and hit complete. Second person will be notified that the form has been started and will be given the form with Section A complete and will fill out Section B. The person who fills Section A cannot see Section B so it appears as though they are completely filling out the form. The person filling out Section B can see the values entered for Section A but cannot edit them.

Can this be done in MS Access and used on SharePoint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see why not. However, when you say form, that not really a typical Access form that lets you edit all records in a table.

How a general form on the Access client side or that of on Access web works is not a whole bit different.

In fact, for user A, if they don't need the part B, then just have them launch/load a form that does not have part B anyway.

The issue(s) here are not so much the form, but issues of security, authentication what means you plan to use to restrict one user's ability over that of another.

Access web services are based on SharePoint. I not tested this, but I do believe that you can resolve row permissions down to individual users.

So building the basic form and certainly preventing one user from opening anther form is quite easy. So you just have the second person launch a different form based on permission.

However, due to the nature of Access being bound forms to tables, the real issue becomes the finer details of security.

I cannot really say that Access is the ideal tool for passing "forms" that are to be filled out and passed around.  InfoPath + SharePoint are far more designed for such a type of workflow in a company.

So an access form is something attached to a table of data. Such forms should not be considered a "form" that is passed around. So forms in Access web are very similar to forms built in FoxPro, VB6, or even those in regular client Access applications.

So when it comes down to building forms that users need to edit data in typical type of application built in Access, then that ease of use and rapid development model now includes the ability of Access to publish those applications to a Web site.

So the nature of the applications you build has not really changed a lot here, It just now that we have a web choice for those typical types of forms built using Access.

Comment: Appreciate the advice. After some research I believe InfoPath + SharePoint would be a better route to take, as you suggested.